# Counting the number of times a word appears in a string?

Tags: python, string

I need to write a simple script to print the number of times the word `'a'` appears in a string. If I use `s.count` it searches for the letter and not the word. My string is:

```
s='This is a sentence with a bunch of words. How can we count the number of words? How can we count the number of times the letter a appears? How can we count the number of times the word a appears?'
```

Comment: Besides `s.count`, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be as follows, using `re` module:

```
num = len(re.findall(r'\ba\b', s))
```

In [python regex syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), `\b` matches a word boundary. The `r`-suffix in front of the pattern string marks it as 'raw', which is required in this example. You might as well wish to compile the regex pattern beforehand:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(word), re.I) # case insensitive
num = len(pattern.findall(s))
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers, a beginner version:

```
s = 'This is a sentence with a bunch of words. How can we count the number of words? How can we count the number of times the letter a appears? How can we count the number of times the word a appears?'
number_of_occurences = 0
for word in s.split():
  if word == 'a':
    number_of_occurences += 1
print number_of_occurences
```

So you split the sentence to words and then for each word, you check if it matches what you want to find and increase a counter.

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution would be to use a filter statement

```
num = len(filter(lambda x: x==a , s.split(" ")))
```

where `a` is the word you are looking for and `s` is the sentence. If you want to make it more robust, you could also set it to split on any white space, punctuation, etc using a regular expression.

Comment: Is filtering a common way of doing this? The script worked and I got the correct answer. I just don't remember using it in class and my notes are on my laptop at home. I have to turn in the assignment by noon and this is the last thing that I have to answer.

Comment: Its a way to do it. There are a lot of ways to go about something like this. Its not necessarily "best" or "most efficient", but its a solution that I like.

Answer (score 0):

A windowing for loop should work. It's not the fastest way to do it, but it's straightforward.

```
def Find_Pattern(Text, Pattern):
    numOfPattern = 0
    for each in range(0, len(Text)-len(Pattern)+1):
       if Text[each:each+len(Pattern)] == Pattern:
           numOfPattern += 1
    return numOfPattern
```

Where `Text` is your input text and where `Pattern` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

as simple as that

```
def count_word(sentence, word):
 x = 0
 for i in sentence.split():
  if i==word:
   x+=1
 return x

print count_word("tha a atedta a","a")
```

Comment: I don't understand why plp are using lambda, filters, re, compile and all this things when the answer is that simple

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I got to class early and confirmed it with classmates. They said the lambda stuff would be too complex and probably not get me credit for the assignment.

Comment: This won't work in all circumstances, for example in the string `"A Saturday afternoon in November was approaching."` (even if you lowercase it)

Comment: edited the line, now it will work anyway :)

Comment: This will calculate any word that ends with an a as a match. For example, `"My soda was bad".lower().count('a ')` will return 1, not 0.

Comment: thanks, you were right, I ve edited it again :P